# Python re.compile uses incorrect ] literally rather than throwing error

Tags: python, regex

So if I have a regex eg: '[ab]c]' then I expect re.compile() to throw an error saying missing '[' but instead it uses the latter ']' literally and matches 'ac]' as a correct string.

I do not follow this behavior and and thus unable to add validation to my regex that a user can input.
Please help.

Comment: FWIW, [the online regex checker agrees with Python](https://regex101.com/r/aN9gQ6/1). Maybe it's actually the way it's "supposed" to work?

Comment: What is the question? What can't you fix by simply not using "invalid" regex? ("Doctor, it hurts when I do *this*" - "Then don't do it") (and yes, it is perfectly correct behaviour)

Comment: i think you need `[ab\]c]` and the behavior is correct

Comment: This looks like an example of the xy problem. Instead of asking how he can match the text he wants to match he asks how to include a bracket inside brackets

Comment: @Racialz This may be a how do I parse this HTML with `regex` hiding in the wind...

Answer (score 1):

In [a specification for PERL regular expressions](http://www.wellho.net/regex/perlre.html), which Python imitates, it says:

> Any single character matches itself, unless it is a
>   metacharacter with a special meaning described here or
>   above.

There are many, many metacharacters listed, but, particularly, a single `]` does not appear to be a metacharacter; only complete `[...]` is. So it would seem that the behavior you encounter is correct according to this spec.

[A specification for "perl compatible" regular expressions](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcrepattern.html#SEC4) gives what it claims to be a comprehensive list of metacharacters, which are:

```
\ ^ $ . [ | ( ) ? * + {
```

and notes that "Most characters stand for themselves in a pattern".

I suspect this is related to the idea of making regexes as concise as possible, by having few invalid patterns.

Answer (score 1):

In REGEX:

- `[]` will error with: Incomplete character class
- `]` matches the character ] literally
- `[` will error with: Incomplete character class

This is a parsing limitation with a lot of bracketed notations and it is not python specific. If you start a meta-squence (`[` <- open bracket) the parser has to match it to a closing bracket or error. `[a[d]` vs `[a[d]*` this is why searches became greedy.

Comment: "this is why searches became greedy" - What does that mean?